# Загрузка изображения на сервер с проверками

Tags: скрипт, php, загрузка

Пробовала загружать фото на сервер, не получается, укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки:

```
if (isset($_FILES['foto']))   {

$foto = $_FILES['foto'];

function isSecurity($foto){
$name = $foto['name'];
$type = $foto['type'];
$size = $foto['size'];

$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4"); 
foreach ($blacklist as $item) {if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $name))return false;}

if (($type != "image/gif") && ($type != "image/png") && ($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg"))return false;

if ($size > 800 * 1024) return false;

}

function LoadFoto($foto){
$type = $foto['type'];
$uploaddir = "avatars/";
$name = md5(microtime()).".".substr($type, strlen("image/"));
if(move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$name)) 
{
setFoto($foto); return true; 
}
else return false;
}

function setFoto($name)
{   
$result1 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO obyavleniya (foto) VALUES ('$name')");
}

if (isSecurity($foto)) LoadFoto($foto);
else $message = "Ошибка при загрузке фото";
}
```

Comment: @Регина, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: А можно узнать, откуда берётся переменная $foto в этом фрагменте кода?

    if (isSecurity($foto)) 
       LoadFoto($foto);

Comment: @Photon с третьей строки кода!

Comment: @Palmervan, когда я спрашивал, там этой строки не было

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я все исправила, но все равно не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИМХО всё дело в том, что ваша проверка возвращает false в 3х разных случаях и не разу не возвращает true.

```
function isSecurity($foto){
$name = $foto['name'];
$type = $foto['type'];
$size = $foto['size'];

$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4"); 
foreach ($blacklist as $item) {if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $name))return false;}

if (($type != "image/gif") && ($type != "image/png") && ($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg"))return false;

if ($size > 800 * 1024) return false;

return true; // <-- тут
}

if (isSecurity($foto)) LoadFoto($foto);
else $message = "Ошибка при загрузке фото";
}
```

P.s. полезно составлять комментарии php-doc для понимания, что же должна возвращать функция

Comment: Да, я уже исправила)

Comment: Не сомневался. Просто как-то напрягает, что за пару месяцев никто не заметил :)

Answer (score 1):

А может проблема кроется в том что у `html` тега `form` отсутствует `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? Это как вариант!

Кусок кода:

```
if (($type != "image/gif") && ($type != "image/png") && ($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg"))return false;
```

Измените на:

```
 if(!in_array($type, array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'))) { return false; }
```

И `blacklist` уже не очень нежен!

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" есть, все работает без проверок, а с проверками - никак.

Comment: Что, больше нет ошибок?